# Integrate MVC 3 Razor with Asp.Net 4.0 in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have developed one ASP.NET (C#) web application in Framework 4. I want to integrate an external module which is developed in MVC 3 Razor. 
How can I integrate this MVC module with my existing ASP.NET web application?
And also how to perform nevigation between them.

Both have master page.

please help me.

give me any sample example if possible.

thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge web.config & global.ascx with mvc.

Add all folder in asp.net project

To redirect to Razor view from web page use

```
Response.RedirectToRoute("Default");
```

where Default Route is

```
routes.MapRoute(<br />
    "Default", // Route name<br />
   "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters<br />
   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "0" } // Parameter defaults<br />
  );<br />
```